# titanium - get the facebook user name?

Tags: facebook, titanium

Using titanium, does anybody have some simple instructions to get the user's facebook name, once signed into facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, here is how you do it:

```
function getFacebookInfo(){
    Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e){
        if (e.success){
            var jsonObject  = JSON.parse(e.result);
            //do something here with these values. They cannot be passed out of this
            //function call... this is an asynchronous call
            //that is, do this:
            saveToDb(jsonObject.first_name);
        } else {
            //some sort of error message here i guess
        }
    });

};
```

Finally, along with `name` and `username`, check out the facebook page for the other variables you can get -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

FINALLY: be aware that this is a **callback**, and titanium won't actually wait for this call to finish. That is, any variable declared to hold the results the returned after the requestWithGraphPAth will *immediately* return, and as a result almost always be empty.

I guess you could make a nifty loop that just... loops until some variable is set to false. And you'd set the variable to false in the callback... but that seems dodgy.

Just make your call back do *everything* else, that is, save to the db etc etc

If you *do* go the route of calling Ti.Facebook.authorise() to log in the user, remember to define

```
Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login',function(e){
    if (e.success){ 
...
...
    } else if (e.error){  } else if (e.cancel) { }
}
```

before the call. And then, in the success bit, you can make a requestWithGraphPath call and so on. I just save all the details to the database and retrieve them each time after that, works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to do any of this, the username is provided in the data response after the login is done.

[Look at the appcelerator documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Facebook-event-login)

Comment: you're right... but i used authorise, so i needed to define a handler etc to handle this. Still, +1 for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code but you can try this:

```
var fbuid = Titanium.Facebook.uid; //this would be the logged user's facebook uid

function fQuery() //this function exec the fql query
{
    var myQuery = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = "+fbuid;

    var data = [];

    Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: myQuery},  function(x)
    {   
        var results = JSON.parse(x.result);
        var username = results[0].name; //user's fb name
    });
};
```

Comment: hm, no - that's using the "request" call which we're encouraged not to do

Comment: also, request is asynchronous... so your username isn't going to get the results. this answer is wrong on every level possible.